# Proof: It is not true that if a partially ordered set has exactly one minimal element, then it must be the smallest element.

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing

$Proof$.
Let $A=\mathbb{Z}\cup\{a\}$, where $\mathbb{Z}$ is ordered in the usual strict linear order, and $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$. Then we have a partial order on $A$. Now since there is no $x\in A$ such that $x<a$, $a$ is minimal, and since for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x-1<x$, $a$ is the only minimal. Finally, since $a<x$ is undefined for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $a$ is not the smallest element.

What does $x<a$ even mean? Since we are talking about the partial order on $A$, i think it means that $x$ and $y$ are elements of $A$. Im confused because someone told me that by definition $x<y$ tells that $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$, but can't the $<$ symbol be used for other relations aswell?

Or is it because for $x\in\mathbb{Z}$, $x<y$ is only valid if $y\in\mathbb{Z}$, e.g you cannot compare an integer with some other type of object.

In general, is $x<y$ only valid if $x$ and $y$ are elements of the same set?

Comment: Your title and body do not match. Are you interested in the general case? Or whether does $\mathbb{Z}$ come from?

Comment: You correctly constructed an example to show that what you claim in your title is true.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven They do match. OP is proving a theorem "it is not true that..." by exhibiting a counterexample. OP: your proof is fine. Was that your question? This site is not intended as a proof-checking machine. I added the proof-checking tag but in that case, [you ought to specify which step you doubt and why](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info).

Comment: @AnneBauval does $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x<y$ imply $y\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: What does it mean for $x$ to be the smallest element of a partially ordered set?

Comment: @TonyK https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_element_and_least_element

Comment: @AnneBauval It's good to see, that at least one of us is able to read :) and clearly that's not me.

Comment: @lightyourassonfire Yes it does, this is equivalent to saying that $a$ is minimal.

Comment: @AnneBauval i edited it to clarify

Answer (score 2):

There is no unwritten rule or convention you are missing. The partial order in the proof is just not explained explicitly and clearly.

What’s intended is that, for $x,y\in A$, $x<_A y$ if and only if $x,y\in\mathbb Z$ and $x<_{\mathbb Z} y$, where $<_{\mathbb Z}$ is the standard order on $\mathbb Z$. (I call the partial order we’re defining on $A$ “$<_A$“ just to avoid ambiguity.)

With that definition, you can show $<_A$ is a partial order on $A$, and that $a$ is uniquely minimal, but not least in $(A,<_A)$.

Answer (score 0):

We **choose** to define a **particular** strict partial order $<$ on $A:=\Bbb Z\cup\{a\}$ (for some fixed $a\notin\Bbb Z$) by:

> $(\forall x,y\in A),$ $x<y$ iff $x,y\in\Bbb Z$ and $x$ is strictly less than $y$ in the usual sense.

For this order, there is no $x\in A$ satisfying $x<a,$ which means that $a$ is minimal. And $a$ is not a least element: it is not even comparable with any other element of $A.$

But all this is a matter of choice, not of "type of objects". We could as well have chosen some other order on $A$ (which would then not be the counterexample we want) by (for instance): $x<y$ iff: either same as before, or $x=a$ and $y\in\Bbb Z.$ For this order, $a$ is the least element of $A.$